# Does phpMyAdmin has any special access to MySQL?

Tags: java, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am developing a cross-platform MySQL administration software in JAVA, similar to phpMyAdmin, but more user-friendly, easier to use. So far, everything works.
The software gains access to the MySQL server with the standard methods like every website: hostname, username, password, port.

Do I need any special access to the MySQL server except for user authentication, in order to make it a full-feature phpMyAdmin-like admin tool?
Does phpMyAdmin has anything special, or it is just a 'website' that communicates with MySQL, like any other website?

Comment: It's just a web site and gains access like any other site, only it is built to work with the database directly rather than obscure DB use.  Nothing 'special' per say. ^^

Comment: You can get the source and check it out yourself, but it is just an interface, nothing special in any other sense. http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

Comment: Only thing you might want to think of is the user rights. You'd need a user with full database rights for a full working clients, not a user with some simple create, update, alter rights for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about phpMyAdmin, its just a client.

Comment: And like other client tool, it has enough permissions as the database user that you provide to the tool.

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin connects to the mysql database just as any other program would, too.

However, you could add some features that would require accessing files on the harddisk directly – for example, it might be nice to be able to watch the server logfiles live. With something like that, you could let the user of your webinterface have a look at the database queries that applications perform or so.